# Can't use options with io.elementary.terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal

For example :

`io.elementary.terminal -h`

produces the following output

```
[DEBUG 21:57:54.738715] Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'io.elementary.terminal.settings'
Usage:
  io.elementary.terminal [OPTION…]
```

> Why do I need this to work?

I have to change "*Terminal to launch console program*" **from** `xterm -T $TITLE -e` **to** elementary's OS (Juno) `io.elementary.terminal -e` in *CodeBlocks*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this works for me in Hera 5.1.3 in codeblocks. Copy paste this to *Settings>Environment settings>Terminal to launch console program*

```
io.elementary.terminal -t $TITLE -x
```

Comment: Yes, I had opened an issue on their GitHub and they patched the code for gnome-terminal style program execution in Juno itself, master branch. I hope they have released it in the newest release. as you say it is working. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed by the developers in the newest release of elementaryOS.